# Why netscape portable runtime library

Tags: updates

As an Ubuntu user, we often have updates. Today I saw an update titled "Netscape portable runtime library" and the file was tagged **libnspr4**.

The only thing I can relate it to is FireFox but I'm not sure.

So why does Ubuntu need a Netscape project component when Netscape is long gone and used to be commercial?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `apt-cache show libnspr4`:

> Maintainer: Ubuntu Mozilla Team 
>   Original-Maintainer: Maintainers of Mozilla-related packages

and

> Description-en: NetScape Portable Runtime Library
>    This library provides platform independent non-GUI operating system
>   facilities including:
>    * threads,
>    * thread synchronisation,
>    * normal file I/O and network I/O,
>    * interval timing and calendar time,
>    * basic memory management (malloc and free),
>    * shared library linking.

As you can see it has its purpose and is being maintained.

Comment: So arey ou saying that it's for the OS or for FireFox?

Comment: I have no idea. If this answer does not meet your needs just say so and I will delete it.

Comment: No, don't delete it. In face you have a +1 for your contribution. But my concern is who needs it - FF or Ubuntu? If it's either, then I wonder how a commercial library can go along a free Open source system.